# Python: Pip failing when adding platform option

Tags: python, pip

My machine has python 2.7 and windows 7 x64. I am trying to download a python 3.5 and Linux compatible version of a package. It works when I pass in the version option, it works when I pass in the platform, but fails when passed in together.

This works for me:

```
pip download --only-binary=:all: --python-version 35 numpy
```

This also works:

```
pip download --only-binary=:all: --platform manylinux1_x86_64 numpy
```

This does not work:

```
pip download --only-binary=:all: --python-version 35 --platform manylinux1_x86_64 numpy

Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement numpy==1.12.1 (from versions: ) 
No matching distribution found for numpy==1.12.1
```

Comment: You mention Python 2.7 and windows 7 x64 then move on to install a Python 3.5 linux version of numpy. Can you elaborate on your setup and requirements? Also, do you have any reason not to use PythonXY/Canopy/Anaconda that are binary distributions coming with numpy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is also necessary to specify the --abi

```
pip download --only-binary=:all: --python-version 35 --abi cp35m --platform manylinux1_x86_64 numpy
```